# Redis Cache + InMemoryCache implementations, we need them both in a configurable way

Tags: c#, .net, redis, in-memory-cache

i have a senario , currently both redis cache and inMemorycache is being used in project.we want something configurable like pick value from Appsetting then initialize either a redis service or in memory cache service..and we can switch between them any time.
Definitely we need to implement IRedisService and IMemoryCache Interfaces in a similar way so that if its switch no exception is thrown.
but is t possible? as both have there own ways of implementing things like setting and getting values etc.

any suggestions on this are welcome.
i am new to this cache stuff

currently trying to implement it but stuck over keeping similar implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look into Redis server assisted client-side caching. https://redis.io/docs/manual/client-side-caching. Some OSS Redis client libraries might not be supporting this yet.